Shift differently the numbers on the top of the bars in a xbar
I want 1% to be shifted left and 4% to be shifted right. It does not matter the quantity; I would like to know how to shift the two values on the two categorical axes differently.
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,
        height=6cm,
        xbar stacked,
        bar width=15pt,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=100,
        enlarge y limits=0.3,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        symbolic y coords={
            The structure and functioning of the Board, 
            Having an effective corporate governance framework},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=3pt, anchor=south},
        nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=0, /tikz/.cd, black},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=0},
        xtick={0,20,...,100},
        axis lines*=left,
        xlabel={Percentage},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},
        reverse legend,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1.5cm},
        legend cell align={left},
        legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[draw=none,#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.25cm,0.1cm);
        },
    ]
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=yellow, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            nodes near coords style={xshift=-5pt}] 
        coordinates {(1,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                     (4,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=gray, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            nodes near coords style={xshift=-3pt, yshift=5pt}] 
        coordinates {(3,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                     (5,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=lime, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            nodes near coords style={xshift=3pt, yshift=1pt}] 
        coordinates {(40,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                     (37,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=green, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            nodes near coords style={xshift=5pt, yshift=1pt}] 
        coordinates {(45,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                     (47,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
        \legend{Strongly Disagree, Disagree, Neutral, Agree, Strongly Agree}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Can you please add a screenshot and add what’s missing in the beginning? Thank you

Done, thank you

With coordinate style/.condition
    coordinate style/.condition=
        {\coordindex==1}{xshift=5pt},
    coordinate style/.condition=
        {\coordindex==2}{xshift=-5pt}, 

\coordindex==1 for The structure and functioning of the Board
\coordindex==2 for Having an effective corporate governance framework
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,
        height=6cm,
        xbar stacked,
        bar width=15pt,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=100,
        enlarge y limits=0.3,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        symbolic y coords={
            The structure and functioning of the Board, 
            Having an effective corporate governance framework},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        %nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=3pt, anchor=south},
        nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=0, /tikz/.cd, black},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=0},
        xtick={0,20,...,100},
        axis lines*=left,
        xlabel={Percentage},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},
        reverse legend,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1.5cm},
        legend cell align={left},
        legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[draw=none,#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.25cm,0.1cm);
        },
    ]
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=yellow, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            % nodes near coords style={xshift=-5pt}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==1}{xshift=5pt},
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==2}{xshift=-5pt},     
    %%%%%%%%%%%            
    ] 
        coordinates {(1,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                    (4,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



when you have more than one cooridnates and \addplot it does nto work.

\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=12cm,
        height=4.5cm,
        xbar stacked,
        bar width=15pt,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=100,
        enlarge y limits=1,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        symbolic y coords={
            The structure and functioning of the Board, 
            Having an effective corporate governance framework},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        %nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\small, yshift=3pt, anchor=center},
        nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=0, /tikz/.cd, black},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=0},
        xtick={0,20,...,100},
        axis lines*=left,
        %xlabel={Percentage},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}},
        reverse legend,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1.5cm},
        legend cell align={left},
        legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[draw=none,#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.25cm,0.1cm);
        },
    ]
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=red, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==0}{xshift=0pt},
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==1}{xshift=0pt},        
    ] 
        coordinates {(0,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                    (0,The structure and functioning of the Board)};        
   
    \addplot+[xbar,fill=yellow, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==0}{xshift=-10pt},
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==1}{xshift=-10pt},     
    ] 
        coordinates {(1,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                    (4,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=gray, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==0}{yshift=10pt},
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==1}{yshift=10pt},     
    ] 
        coordinates {(3,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                    (5,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=lime, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==0}{xshift=0pt},
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==1}{xshift=0pt},     
    ] 
        coordinates {(40,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                    (37,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
        \addplot+[xbar,fill=green, draw=none, 
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, 
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==0}{xshift=0pt},
            coordinate style/.condition=
                {\coordindex==1}{xshift=0pt},     
    ] 
        coordinates {(45,Having an effective corporate governance framework) 
                    (47,The structure and functioning of the Board)};
        \legend{Strongly Disagree, Disagree, Neutral, Agree, Strongly Agree}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


